# OOTB: Manage employee skills requirements and departments in SharePoint

Tags: list, lookup-column, out-of-the-box

Need to create a log and a matrix for tracking requirements for job skills, required and after completed.

Employees by location and current rank.
Skills by categories, levels, and areas.
Master list that shows requirements and links to documentation.
Track completion of required skills.

how can I best utilize SharePoint lists?

Comment: You can link SharePoint Lists with the "Lookup Column". Give it a try and create two lists in SharePoint. One list could be "Locations" where you add your locations. Another list could be "Employees". In that list add a choice or text column for rank as well as a "Lookup Column" on "Locations" for the location. Now you can use locations information in that list. With this knowledge you can create some lists connected to each other building the management platform you need for your employees and skills.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did try this and it worked out well.

Comment: Hi Jeannette, I postet the comment as answer on your question. You could mark as answer if it worked. So your question will not remain "open". Thank you and happy sharepointing!

Answer (score 0):

You can link SharePoint Lists with the "Lookup Column". Give it a try and create two lists in SharePoint. One list could be "**Locations**" where you add your locations. Another list could be "**Employees**". In that list add a choice or text column for rank as well as a "Lookup Column" on "**Locations**" for the location. Now you can use locations information in that list. With this knowledge you can create some lists connected to each other building the management platform you need for your employees and skills.